# "Error: HttpStatus cannot be resolved to a variable" How to resolve This?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am getting error in below code at line 2: `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)`. Error is: "**HttpStatus cannot be resolved to a variable**". What imports are required for this? Am i missing any necessary jar file? Any help?

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String validateUser( @PathVariable( "id" ) String id){

     Return "User Validated"
}
```

Comment: import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
and jar  spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Thanks Safwan, Putting first import solved my problem.That should actually be there in eclipse quick fix suggestion window. But that was not there coz of unknown reason. Anyway problem is fixed now.

Comment: I will add as answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
```